# disable button is not working while using ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs

Initially the value of button is disable because value of button is true so the button is disabled.After selecting the checkbox now the button should be able to click. But it is not able to click :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[0]" ng-true-value="'a'">a
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[1]" ng-true-value="'s'">s
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[2]" ng-true-value="'d'">d
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[3]" ng-true-value="'f'">f
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[4]" ng-true-value="'g'">g
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled='!formData.week.length' ng-click=a(formData)>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.a = function(x) {
        console.log(x);
        a = [1, 2, 3];
        console.log(a);
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-disabled always checks for length. But you actually need to check the boolean value of your checkbox to satisfy the scenario you are trying to achieve.

I have updated your code to the code below

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[0]"  ng-true-value="'a'">a
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[1]"  ng-true-value="'s'">s
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[2]"  ng-true-value="'d'">d
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[3]"  ng-true-value="'f'">f

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[4]"  ng-true-value="'g'">g


<input type="submit" ng-disabled='formData.week[0]==false &&

formData.week[1]==false &&
formData.week[2]==false &&
formData.week[3]==false &&
formData.week[4]==false



' ng-click=a(formData)>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.formData = {}
$scope.formData.week = []
$scope.formData.week[0]=false;
$scope.formData.week[1]=false;
$scope.formData.week[2]=false;
$scope.formData.week[3]=false;
$scope.formData.week[4]=false;


   });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have just added some values in the controller because you haven't provided them all completely, just copy paste the code, it will work

Answer (score 0):

change `ng-disabled='!formData.week.length'`

to

```
ng-disabled='!(!!formData.week[0] || !!formData.week[1] || !!formData.week[2] || !!formData.week[3] || !!formData.week[4])'
```

check out the working example : https://plnkr.co/edit/JOARO1NwgunCw5Zcyvpo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is something to understand

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[0]"  ng-true-value="'a'">a
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[1]"  ng-true-value="'s'">s
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[2]"  ng-true-value="'d'">d
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[3]"  ng-true-value="'f'">f
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[4]"  ng-true-value="'g'">g
  <input type="submit" ng-disabled='!formData.week.length' ng-click=a(formData)>
</div>
```

So when you are applied NgModel as `formData.week[0]` so it will form the scope variable `formData` something like that

```
{
  "week" :{"0":true,"1" : true", "2" : "false"
}
```

as you have not declared `formData.week`  as an array. So for this object to be checked on length you need to make a function like

```
<input type="submit" ng-disabled='!checkLength()' ng-click=a(formData)>
```

the function will look like

```
$scope.checkLength = function(){
  if($scope.formData && $scope.formData.week && Object.keys($scope.formData.week).length > 0)
    return true;
  else 
    return false;
}
```

Moreover if you want the button enabled only when any of the checkboxes is true. then you may modify the function

```
$scope.checkLength = function(){
 if($scope.formData && $scope.formData.week && Object.keys($scope.formData.week).length > 0) {
   var point = 0;
   for(var i=0;i< Object.keys($scope.formData.week).length;i++){
       if($scope.formData.week[i] == true){
         point++; 
         break;
       }
   }
   if(point>0) return true;
   else return false;
 }
 else 
   return false;
 }
```